# How to use DATE_PART(MONTH, month) on DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Consider the following snippet:

```
Map<String, String> expressionAttributesNames = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();

expressionAttributesNames.put("#completeDatefield", "completeDatefield");

expressionAttributeValues.put(":onlyMonth", new AttributeValue().withN(Long.toString(1)));

DynamoDBQueryExpression<Entity> dynamoDBQueryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Entity>()
        .withKeyConditionExpression("date_part(month, #completeDatefield) = :onlyMonth")
        .withExpressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributesNames)
        .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);


return dynamoDBMapper.query(Entity.class, dynamoDBQueryExpression);
```

Is there a way to extract only the month from the 'completeDatefield' DynamoDB attribute in a similar way it can be done on PostgreSQL using date_part ?

Comment: There is no `Date` datatype in DynamoDB. Its representation of Java dates is using a String. The only thing you can do is extract the substring that represents the month.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do what you are wanting to do in this way. A key condition expression requires the the partition key be an equality operation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions). You can do partial matches on the sort key, but they are all limited to either using the entire string or using the `begins_with` function. So in order to do a match on the month you'd need to either have the month be the partition key (don't do that) or you'd need it to be at least the first part of the sort key.